# Second SATA drive stopped working (after lion upgrade)

Tags: macos, ssd, sata

Since I upgraded to Lion, my second SATA drive stopped working. The issue occurs only for reading files, not writing. I can unmount it, but I can't rename nor delete files.

I have two SSDs installed in my MacBook Pro and when I look at 'System Information' it lists both drives. So they are properly recognized.

However, the first drive is listed as:

```
"Solid State SATA"
```

and the second (working) one is listed as

```
"Flash Storage"
```

Both drives are formatted as OS X Journaled, so they are of the same format.

Does someone has any idea what's going on over here? And how can I solve this?

Comment: By any chance is the second SSD installed where the MacBooks Optical drive would normally be?

Answer (score 1):

Have you [updated your EFI](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1450)?  [Lots of potential problems](http://blog.macsales.com/11895-2011-macbook-pro-sata-problems-resolved) depending on the drive and the model of MacBook.

In particular it appears that SATA 3.0 drives (6.0 Gbps) are not well supported. The EFI update resolves some problems, but not others. Is the read only drive in the optical bay? That would be consistent with the kind of problems reported.

Answer (score 0):

> It works for only reading, not writing. I can unmount it, I can't rename files, I can't delete files.

Right click on it in Finder, go to "Get Info". In the "Sharing and Permissions" at the bottom, click the little lock, type in your password and allow yourself to read and write. Also try checking "Ignore ownership on this volume".

If that doesn't work, try formatting it with Disk Utility again.

Comment: The drive is read/write. I just formatted it by taking it out, attaching as usb drive and it was fine. but when i install ANY (ssd?) drive into the 2nd sata slot it has the same issues

Comment: Gonna have to ponder that one for a while ...